# Getting path to Drupal root while in module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am not sure if this is an issue with my current setup, or what I want to do.

I have a module that is programatically creating nodes in my Drupal 6 site, and within each I have to provide links in between various nodes.

I basically have a few `foreach` loops, and within each I have the current path.

For instance:

```
foreach ($page->category as $category) {
  $category_link = "category/" . $category['id'];

  // generate category pages
  ...
  $content = "<a href='$category_link'>".$category['name']."</a>";
  _create_node($content);

  foreach ($category->article as $article) {
    $article_link = $category_link . "/article/" . $article['id'];

    // generate article page
    $content = "<a href='$category_link'>".$category['name']."</a>";
    $content .= "<a href='$article_link'>".$article['name']."</a>";
    _create_node($content);
  }
}
```

The issue that I'm seeing is that the link seems to be continually built up.
For instance, in the main category pages it is fine (I'll see `category/1234`), and the article link will be fine, but the category link will seem to be longer than it should.  Basically, I'll end up seeing:

```
category/1234/article/5678/category/1234
```

My first thought was to make use of `$base_url` and just create absolute paths, however whenever I try printing that variable from my module it is completely empty.  This is on a local server, however when I move it to production Drupal isn't installed at the root, so I can't simply add a slash to the front of the link.

Comment: Did you try `unset($category_link);` at the very end of your first `foreach`?

Comment: I did...it seems to be because my current location is past category/id/paper/id, and Drupal auto-appends the extra URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$GLOBALS['base_path']` to get the base path.

Comment: I wish I had more than 1 upvote to give you.  Everything I could find from Google involved `$base_path`

Answer (score 1):

`$GLOBALS['base_path']` will work, but you are accessing a global variable that ALSO contains some things like your database connection info and some other important stuff. So with a slip of the finger you could muck up other things. I prefer `base_path()` which does the same thing but is a modicum safer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
global $base_url;
```

For path to themes folder use

```
path_to_theme()
```

You can use `base_path()` but that will not provide you with the domain name.
Base url will provide you the complete url like : **www.example.com**
`base_path()` will give you : **/**
`path_to_theme()` will give you : **sites/all/themes/yourthemename**